# Need to use addEventListener instead of @HostListener

Tags: angular

I am working with an special browser extension that demands I add an event listener to an existing list of listeners.

As such, I am not able to use @HostListener, since it just assign an event listener to elements.

In my component's constructor, I make a call like this:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.OnBeforeUnload);
```

However, I never get a call to my OnBeforeUnload handler.

How can I use `window.addEventListene`r to add an event listener to the window object?

**Update 1:**

The very same function `this.OnBeforeUnload` works perfectly fine with `@HostListener` setup. It is not working with the addEventListener syntax I mentioned above. There is something wrong with the addEventListener syntax I am using.

Comment: Adding event listeners manually like you do works perfectly well with Angular. Try another event - for example `click` or `resize`. On which browser did you experienced this? And what's in the callback function? `beforeunload` event has some constraints regarding callback's content. Also some browsers don't support this event.

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski, thank you for help. Please see my update.

Comment: Are you write "declare window:any" in your component?

Comment: Possibly because the 'this' is referring to the window object rather than the component.  Try window.addEventListner('beforeunload', this.OnBeforeUnload).bind(this)